# Want to delete the relation from the relation tree but i dont know where i am wrong

Tags: javascript, java, list, relation

help me out in deleting particular relation

```
Person=Alex Relation=Brothers
```

Expected Output should be

```
Brothers=John,Joe
Husband=Bern Wife=Julia
```

The application should add Julia as a spouse for Bern.
now i want to delete the relation between Bern and wife julia and i am not able to do

```
Person=Bern Relation=Wife
```

Should return output as:

Wife=Julia

$ run_application

Input: Husband=Bern Wife=Julia

Output: Welcome to the family, Julia!

Input: Person=Bern Relation=Wife

Output: Wife=Julia

```java
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    class Person {
    private String name;
    private Gender gender;
    private List<Relation> relations = new ArrayList<>();

    Person(String name, Gender gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



    public List<Relation> getRelations() {
        return relations;
    }



    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }



    public void addRelation(Relation relation) {
        relations.add(relation);
    }


    public void deleteRelation(Relation relation) {
        relations.remove(relation);
    }
    }

    class Relation {
    private TreeRelationType type;
    private Person person1;
    private Person person2;

    Relation(TreeRelationType type, Person person1, Person person2) {
        this.type = type;
        this.person1 = person1;
        this.person2 = person2;
    }

    public TreeRelationType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Person getPerson2() {
        return person2;
    }


    }

    enum TreeRelationType {
        SPOUSE, PARENT, CHILD
    }

    enum Gender {
       MALE, FEMALE
     }

     enum RelationType {
         FATHER, MOTHER, BROTHER, SON,GRANDCHILDREN, DAUGHTER,  AUNT, HUSBAND, WIFE
      }

    class InvalidInputException extends Exception {
       static final long serialVersionUID = -3387516993334229948L;

       public InvalidInputException(String message) {
           super(message);
     }

     }

    public class FamilyTree {
        private Person root;
        private Map<String, Boolean> visted = new HashMap<>();



    private Gender fetchGender(RelationType type) {
    if(RelationType.MOTHER.equals(type)||RelationType.DAUGHTER.equals(type)||          RelationType.WIFE.equals(type))
            return Gender.FEMALE;
        else
            return Gender.MALE;
    }

    private TreeRelationType fetchTreeRelationType(RelationType type) {
        if (RelationType.MOTHER.equals(type) || RelationType.FATHER.equals(type))
            return TreeRelationType.CHILD;
        else if (RelationType.HUSBAND.equals(type) || RelationType.WIFE.equals(type))
            return TreeRelationType.SPOUSE;
        else
            return TreeRelationType.PARENT;
    }


    public void addPerson(String name1, RelationType type1, String name2, RelationType type2)
            throws InvalidInputException {
        TreeRelationType relationType1 = fetchTreeRelationType(type1);
        TreeRelationType relationType2 = fetchTreeRelationType(type2);
        Gender gender1 = fetchGender(type1);
        Gender gender2 = fetchGender(type2);
        if (this.root == null) {
            Person person1 = new Person(name1, gender1);
            Person person2 = new Person(name2, gender2);
            this.root = person1;
            addRelation(relationType1, person1, relationType2, person2);
        } else {
            Person person1 = findPerson(this.root, name1);
            if (person1 == null) {
                throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid Input");
            }
            Person person2 = new Person(name2, gender2);
            addRelation(relationType1, person1, relationType2, person2);
            if (TreeRelationType.CHILD.equals(relationType1)) {
                for (Relation relation : person1.getRelations()) {
                    if (TreeRelationType.SPOUSE.equals(relation.getType())) {
                        person1 = relation.getPerson2();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                deleteRelation(relationType1, person1, relationType2, person2);
            }
        }
     }

    public void deleteperson(String name1, RelationType type1, String name2, RelationType type2)
            throws InvalidInputException {
        TreeRelationType relationType1 = fetchTreeRelationType(type1);
        TreeRelationType relationType2 = fetchTreeRelationType(type2);
        Gender gender1 = fetchGender(type1);
        Gender gender2 = fetchGender(type2);

            Person person1 = findPerson(this.root, name1);
            if (person1 == null) {
                throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid Input");
            }
            Person person2 = findPerson(this.root, name2);
                if (person2 == null) {
                    throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid Input");
            }

            deleteRelation(relationType1, person1, relationType2, person2);
            if (TreeRelationType.CHILD.equals(relationType1)) {
                for (Relation relation : person1.getRelations()) {
                    if (TreeRelationType.SPOUSE.equals(relation.getType())) {
                        person1 = relation.getPerson2();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                addRelation(relationType1, person1, relationType2, person2);
            }

    }


    private Person findPerson(Person cur, String name) {
        this.visted.put(cur.getName(), Boolean.TRUE);
        if (cur.getName().equals(name)) {
            this.visted.clear();
            return cur;

        } else {
            for (Relation relation : cur.getRelations()) {
                Person person2 = relation.getPerson2();
                if (!visted.containsKey(person2.getName())) {
                    Person person = findPerson(person2, name);
                    if (person != null) {
                        return person;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    private void addRelation(TreeRelationType type1, Person person1, TreeRelationType type2, Person person2) {
        Relation relation1 = new Relation(type1, person1, person2);
        person1.addRelation(relation1);
        Relation relation2 = new Relation(type2, person2, person1);
        person2.addRelation(relation2);
    }

    private void deleteRelation(TreeRelationType type1, Person person1, TreeRelationType type2, Person person2) {
        Relation relation1 = new Relation(type1, person1, person2);
        person1.deleteRelation(relation1);
        Relation relation2 = new Relation(type2, person2, person1);
        person2.deleteRelation(relation2);
    }

    private List<Person> fetchChildren(String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        List<Person> children = new ArrayList<>();
        Person person = findPerson(this.root, name);
        if (person == null) {
            throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid Input");
        }
        for (Relation relation : person.getRelations()) {
            if (TreeRelationType.CHILD.equals(relation.getType())) {
                children.add(relation.getPerson2());
            }
        }
        return children;
    }

    private List<Person> fetchParents(String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        List<Person> parents = new ArrayList<>();
        Person person = findPerson(this.root, name);
        if (person == null) {
            throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid Input");
        }
        for (Relation relation : person.getRelations()) {
            if (TreeRelationType.PARENT.equals(relation.getType())) {
                parents.add(relation.getPerson2());

            }
        }
        return parents;
    }

    private Person fetchFather(String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        Person father = null;
        List<Person> parents = fetchParents(name);
        for (Person person : parents) {
            if (Gender.MALE.equals(person.getGender()))
                father = person;
        }
        return father;
    }

    private Person fetchMother(String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        Person mother = null;
        List<Person> parents = fetchParents(name);
        for (Person person : parents) {
            if (Gender.FEMALE.equals(person.getGender()))
                mother = person;
        }
        return mother;
    }

    private List<Person> fetchSiblings(String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        List<Person> siblings = new ArrayList<>();
        Person father = fetchFather(name);
        if (father != null) {
            List<Person> children = fetchChildren(father.getName());
            for (Person person : children) {
                if (!person.getName().equals(name)) {
                    siblings.add(person);
                }
            }
        }
        return siblings;
    }

    private List<Person> fetchBrothers(String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        List<Person> brothers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Person> siblings = fetchSiblings(name);
        for (Person person : siblings) {
            if (Gender.MALE.equals(person.getGender())) {
                brothers.add(person);
            }
        }
        return brothers;
    }



    private List<Person> fetchGrandChildren(String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        List<Person> children = fetchChildren(name);
        List<Person> grandChildren = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Person person : children) {
            grandChildren.addAll(fetchChildren(person.getName()));
        }

        return grandChildren;
    }





    private List<Person> fetchAunts(String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        List<Person> aunts = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Person> parents = fetchParents(name);
        for (Person person : parents) {
            List<Person> siblings = fetchSiblings(person.getName());
            for (Person sibling : siblings) {
                if (Gender.FEMALE.equals(sibling.getGender())) {
                    aunts.add(sibling);
                } else {
                    Optional<Person> spouce = Optional.ofNullable(fetchSpouce(sibling.getName()));
                    if (spouce.isPresent()) {
                        aunts.add(spouce.get());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return aunts;
    }



    private Person fetchSpouce(String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        Person spouce = null;
        Person person = findPerson(this.root, name);
        if (person == null) {
            throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid Input");
        }
        for (Relation relation : person.getRelations()) {
            if (TreeRelationType.SPOUSE.equals(relation.getType())) {
                spouce = relation.getPerson2();
                break;
            }
        }
        return spouce;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InvalidInputException {
        FamilyTree tree = new FamilyTree();
        tree.addPerson("Dilshada", RelationType.MOTHER, "Laraib", RelationType.SON);
        tree.addPerson("Dilshada", RelationType.WIFE, "Mushtaq", RelationType.HUSBAND);
        tree.addPerson("Dilshada", RelationType.MOTHER, "Laieba", RelationType.DAUGHTER);
        tree.addPerson("Mushtaq", RelationType.FATHER, "Farheen", RelationType.DAUGHTER);
        tree.addPerson("Mushtaq", RelationType.BROTHER, "Ashraf", RelationType.BROTHER);
        tree.addPerson("Ashraf", RelationType.HUSBAND, "Kulsum", RelationType.WIFE);
        tree.addPerson("Mushtaq", RelationType.SON, "Nani", RelationType.MOTHER);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice;
        do{
            System.out.println("1.  Add Relation\n2.  View Relation\n3.  Delete Relation\n4.  Exit\n");
            System.out.println("Enter Your Choice");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {

                case 1:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter The {name1}={relationtype1} {name2}={relationtype2}");
                        sc.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
                        String inputString = sc.nextLine();
                        if (!inputString.isEmpty()) {
                            String[] input = inputString.split(" ");


                            String name1 = input[0].split("=")[1];
                            String name2 = input[1].split("=")[1];
                            RelationType type1 = RelationType.valueOf(input[0].split("=")[0].toUpperCase());
                            RelationType type2 = RelationType.valueOf(input[1].split("=")[0].toUpperCase());
                            tree.addPerson(name1, type1, name2, type2);
                            System.out.println("Welcome to the family, " + name2 + "!");

                        }

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    break;

                case 2:

                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter The {name} {relationtype}");

                        sc.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
                        String inputString = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(inputString);
                        if (!inputString.isEmpty()) {
                            String[] input = inputString.split(" ");
                            String relation = input[1];
                            String name = input[0];
                            String value = relation.toUpperCase();

                            if (value.charAt(value.length() - 1) == 'S') {
                                value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
                            }

                            RelationType relationType = RelationType.valueOf(value);
                            switch (relationType) {

                                case FATHER:
                                    Optional<Person> father = Optional.ofNullable(tree.fetchFather(name));
                                    if (father.isPresent()) {
                                        System.out.println(relation + "=" + tree.fetchFather(name).getName());
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case MOTHER:
                                    Optional<Person> mother = Optional.ofNullable(tree.fetchMother(name));
                                    if (mother.isPresent()) {
                                        System.out.println(relation + "=" + tree.fetchMother(name).getName());
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case BROTHER:
                                    System.out.println(relation + "=" + tree.fetchBrothers(name).stream()
                                            .map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
                                    break;


                                case GRANDCHILDREN:
                                    System.out.println(relation + "=" + tree.fetchGrandChildren(name).stream()
                                            .map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
                                    break;

                                case AUNT:
                                    System.out.println(relation + "=" + tree.fetchAunts(name).stream().map(Person::getName)
                                            .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
                                    break;


                                case WIFE:
                                    Optional<Person> spouce = Optional.ofNullable(tree.fetchSpouce(name));
                                    if (spouce.isPresent()) {
                                        System.out.println(relation + "=" + tree.fetchSpouce(name).getName());
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }


                        }

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    break;
                case 3:
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter The {name1}={relationtype1} {name2}={relationtype2}");
                        sc.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
                        String inputString = sc.nextLine();
                        if (!inputString.isEmpty()) {
                            String[] input = inputString.split(" ");


                            String name1 = input[0].split("=")[1];
                            String name2 = input[1].split("=")[1];
                            RelationType type1 = RelationType.valueOf(input[0].split("=")[0].toUpperCase());
                            RelationType type2 = RelationType.valueOf(input[1].split("=")[0].toUpperCase());

                            System.out.println(name1 +" "+name2+" "+type1+" "+type2);
                            tree.deleteperson(name1, type1, name2, type2);
                            System.out.println("Deleted from the family, " + name2 + "!");

                        }

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Existing");
                    break;

            }
        }while(choice !=4);
    }

    }
```

help me in correcting case 3 in main method of deleting relation

Comment: This has nothing to do with python so why have you tagged it as such?

Comment: sorry bro i was just filling the tags and accidently wrote python there.